# Nested xml response in spring boot with Kotlin

Tags: xml, spring-boot, kotlin

I want a xml response of a POST request like this:

```
<Outer>
    <abc>1</abc>
    <Inner>
        <def>2</def>
    </Inner>
</Outer>
```

but I'm getting this:

```
<Outer>
    <abc>1</abc>
</Outer>
```

Here is the code:

Kotlin data class:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Outer {
    val abc = 1
    @XmlRootElement
    class Inner {val def = 2}
}
```

Kotlin Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
class Controller {

    @PostMapping("/abc")
    fun registerByMail() : Outer {
        return Outer()
    }
}
```

Please tell me, where I'm doing wrong. I'm pretty new to both Kotlin and Spring-boot.

Comment: You need to add an instance of the inner class to the outer one `class Outer { val inner = Inner() }`, The position of the definition of the `Inner`  class isn't actually relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept your model, but used jackson-dataformat-xml instead of JAXB and a GET request instead of POST:

```
@RestController
class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/abc")
    fun registerByMail() : Outer {
        return Outer()
    }

    @JacksonXmlRootElement
    class Outer(val abc: Int = 1) {

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Inner")
        val inner = Inner(2)

        data class Inner(val def: Int)
    }
}
```

Your mistake is that you didn't provide an instance of Inner, you just provide a class definition. I used a data class for inner (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html), but you could also use a simple class, with primary constructor like I did.